# How do I get receiving list on jquery UI sortable with over?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using something similar to this: 
[jquery ui sortable connect lists](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)
and I want to get the receiving list on over event.
Here is my code:

```
    $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        cursor: "move",
        over : function(event, ui){
        //there is ui.sender but not receiver 
     }

}).disableSelection();
```

Can I not do this with just sortable widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiving list will be the `event target` and the `this` of the `over` function. You can access it like this:

```
 $( ".connectedSortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        cursor: "move",
        over : function(event, ui){
            var receiver = event.target;//or this. Both will get you the HTML element, 
                                        //use $(event.target)/$(this) if you want the jquery object
     }

}).disableSelection();
```